# Dúvida sobre controle de acesso

Tags: mysql, android, web-service, segurança

Estou querendo fazer uma aplicação **Android** que realiza **CRUD** em um banco de dados **MYSQL**.

Já pesquisei que o caminho para se fazer isso é utilizando um **Webservice**.

Sou novo nessa área mas já fiz um simples via PHP em REST e andei pesquisando sobre eles. Porém, até agora não vi um Webservice que tem sistema de autorização de acesso como um banco de dados comum. Ou seja, **qualquer um que acessar o endereço do meu webservice, terá acesso a qualquer informação do meu banco de dados**.

Queria saber se existe algum que utiliza algum sistema de segurança para não autorizar acesso indevido que seja mais voltado para o meio que estou utilizando, no caso o Android.

Edit: Depois ler os comentários e de pesquisar e pesquisar, estou pensando em eu mesmo criar um sistema de Controle de Acesso. É recomendado ou não?

Comment: veja no firebases se te ajuda

Comment: Muitas aplicações web fornecem serviços utilizando Tokens para autenticação.
Por exemplo o https://www.themoviedb.org/. Você pode utilizar soluções prontas como por exemplo o: https://jwt.io/

Comment: Olá Icaro, não sei te mencionar aqui mas o firebases que você está falando é o serviço da Google? 
MBecker, estou dando uma olhada no link que passou.

Comment: Outra coisa que não entendo é que a maioria das pessoas que usam banco de dados externo precisam de controle de acesso para o mesmo, porém para uma necessidade tão popular, parece que está carente de informações na net ou estou procurando tudo errado.